# Subtract cells when the condition matches in a Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I subtract horizontal multiple cells when the condition matches.

If match found then return subtracted value if not then return current value.

I tried the below formula but not able to do multiple matches

```
=IF(ROW(A3)=2,0,D3-D2)
```

```
    Date    Type    Content Value   Answer
    1-Oct-18    Type 1  Content 1   7   7
    1-Oct-18    Type 1  Content 1   7   0
    1-Oct-18    Type 1  Content 1   9   2
    2-Oct-18    Type 2  Content 1   8   8
    2-Oct-18    Type 2  Content 2   10  10
    2-Oct-18    Type 2  Content 2   3   -7
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in E2 and copy down:

```
=D2-SUMIFS($E$1:E1,$B$1:B1,B2,$C$1:C1,C2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks its working as expected .. Can we change the name to InValid when it returns current value if its not matches ..@Scott Craner

Comment: No, it needs to be a number.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check the row here as your current formula does. `ROW(A3)` will always return the row. Thus your test statement can be reduced to `3 = 2` which will always show `TRUE`

---

The equation you are looking for is `=IF(A2=A1, D2-D1, 0)`